# No matching version found for internal-slot@^1.0.3

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I'am facing a problem with npm installation.
I am trying to make an `npm install` on an Angular application but i got a message depicted on the picture above :
**No matching version found for internal-slot@^1.0.3**

I have tried to check which package use the internal-slot (`npm ls internal-slot`), but returns me empty!
So to figure out from where this problem is produced, I removed set of npm dependencies by set, and i made an install after each modification, but unfortunately the problem persist.

Any kind of help will be appreciable!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

NPM told you which package this is a dependency of: `es-abstract` (second to last line).

Looking at NPM, I see that [internal-slot](https://www.npmjs.com/package/internal-slot?activeTab=versions) has a most recent version of `1.0.3`, which tells me there might be a conflict with another Angular dependency (or dependency chain).

Try try adding the package directly to your project, but with an exact version number:

```
npm i internal-slot@1.0.3 --save-exact
```

This will specify an exact version, not a "compatible" one (no `^` prefix on the version in `package.json`), and will likely override (or expose) other dependencies.

Comment: I am using an internal registry  and i couldn't install 1.0.3 version; only the 1.0.2 version exist on it.